# MYSQL-Changing column data type with full data and relationship dependancy

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I've a quick question. Is there a possible way for me to change my column data type from INT to BIGINT without me having to remove all data and relationships? I keep getting errors saying

```
#1025 - Error on rename of '.#sql-27a4_7d' to '.comment' (errno: 150)
```

My table structures are like so:

```
comment_id int AI pk;
user_id int fk;
```

ps** I am using the phpmyadmin GUI version. Thanks

Comment: You can use alter table and can change the data types from there.

Comment: @Make i could not alter anything as long as it is either bounded with PK or FK relations

Comment: I think you have to drop the foraign key constaint, change the datatype of both column and readd the constraint.

Comment: @Jens wow omg really? I have like tons of tables that are related to each other and I have to do it manually like that? :'(

Comment: @KennyYap are the all related on the filed you have to change?

Comment: @Jens yes... apparently if you change one of any PK's data type, the FK that is mapped to the PK data type must be changed also... that's why I am surveying on any other more efficient way of doing it...

Comment: You can try to dump the data change it in the dump and reimport the data. I have no other idea.

Comment: @Jens taken your advise, what I do is shut down my server for 10mins, export the whole DB into a sql file and divided it into 10 section for 10 people and we manage to change everything into what we want then compile the files together and import it to the server again... although its not the best way of doing since you may face data corruption, but it does what we wanted... cheers mate :)